# Automate Release Action from my Graph Extension

Tags: acumatica

How can I automate the Release button from my Graph Extension, I've extended the JournalWithSubEntry graph. I added a journal voucher transaction via code, the only problem now is how do I release the transaction I've added. Below is my sample code, and it gives me the error

> cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead in file

```
List<GLDocBatch> list = new List<GLDocBatch>();
list.Add(newdoc);          
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this.Base, delegate() { this.Base.ReleaseBatch(list); });
```

Answer (score 1):

As ReleaseBatch is static you should use JournalWithSubEntry.ReleaseBatch instead of Base.ReleaseBatch.